# django, How to use bulk_create(objs,batch_size=None)

Tags: python, django

In `bulk_create()`, what does `batch_size` means?
I tried two codes,

```
Person.objects.bulk_create([
    Person (name='Tom', age='24', job='student', hobby='football'),
    Person (name='Steve', age='33', job='doctor', hobby='movie'),
    Person (name='Mike', age='55', job='professor', hobby='tennis'),
    ])
```

and

```
Person.objects.bulk_create([
    Person (name='Tom', age='24', job='student', hobby='football'),
    Person (name='Steve', age='33', job='doctor', hobby='movie'),
    Person (name='Mike', age='55', job='professor', hobby='tennis'),
    ], batch_size=2)
```

In second case I added `batch_size` but that two codes didn't have differences.

What `batch_size` means? How to use this `batch_size`?

Comment: What about [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) is unclear to you?

Comment: I read it. It says 'batch_size' controls how many objs are created in single query. So I tried second code and expected only two objs are created. But all objs are created..

Comment: What? Why would you expect only two objects to be created? You've asked for three objects, that is how many are created. It just takes two queries to do it.

Comment: I think it means in batches it up into queries of that size.  So instead of making 1 call to save all 3 records it made 2 calls, the first time saving 2 records and the second time saving the remaining one

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks!!  (-:

Answer (score 4):

Consider you have list of objects to be created is around 10000 and if you specify batch size like 100, every 100 objects are created in bulk create. For smaller list you won't see any difference. But for bigger list like more than 10000 with variable batch size.

Answer (score 3):

The `batch_size` parameter controls how many objects are created in single query. The default is to create all objects in one batch, except for SQLite where the default is such that at most 999 variables per query are used.

For example if you are going to perform a bulk create of 100k objects and set a `batch_size` of 1000, django is going to perform 100 queries to complete the request (Each query creating 1000 objects).